What grass or weed is this?
I had to reseed my lawn after a room addition. I let the weeds germinatr for months and killed everything with Roundup. I then laid down premium seed but I am wondering if there was a bunch of fescue in it. Is this field type fescue, crabgrass, quackgrass...?
If it is fescue and clumping, and I keep overseeding with Kentucky bluegrass, will it eventually die off?




Please be aware that it is incredibly hard to ID grasses without a picture or reference to the seed

@Arrow yeah. I used to have a nice site bookmarked to help but it's no longer up. I'm pretty sure it's a fescue. Not quack or crab. I actually painted it with a sponge brush as it was much higher than the KGB under it.

@EvilElf Yeah, there are multiple sites that I use for IDing grasses, but none of them are super useful without the seed. I will go through the options for your area and ID it for you, but it will take some time :)
